# Rendering a minecraft character has very weird lighting to it

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

Whenever I try and render a minecraft character image using Black Plasma Studios Rig, it has a very odd blue-ish lighting to it. Earlier today I rendered using the same rig and essentially the same image and it didn't have it. I didn't do anything to make shadows, etc. it just happened. I'm new to blender and I use cycles.

[image][image: before the weird coloration]

[image]

Comment: To be able to help you please provide information like render settings or, better, consider uploading your blend file to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3716" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3716/)

Comment: I changed a setting under Light Paths from Integrator Presets to Direct Light and it has fixed most of it. However, some blue-ish spots remain. [link](http://prntscr.com/gbo8ei)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you try to achieve in the end, but your lighting setup seems pretty freaky, or just extends my understanding.   ;)

For a beautiful and simple lighting in cycles just connect a plain white background node to the world surface output, like in the screenshot below.

[image: cycles simple background lighting]